# How do I export result of visdiff of two models programmatically (Matlab versions <= R2016b)?

Tags: matlab

I am comparing two models using visdiff. I can see the results as a comparison tab. I see options on the GUI to export results in different format.
How do I export these results programmatically?

I am able to export it for non-model files.
But for model files it throws following error:
Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.

```
Error in linediff>tokenize (line 153)
    cls = tok_class(double(s));

Error in linediff (line 18)
tok1 = tokenize(line1,ignore_whitespace);

Error in textdiff>i_CreateHTML/writeModifiedLine (line 158)
    [newline1,newline2] = linediff(line1,line2,showchars,ignore_whitespace);

Error in textdiff>i_CreateHTML (line 464)
            writeModifiedLine(line1,a1(n),line2,a2(n));

Error in textdiff (line 42)
    htmlOut=i_CreateHTML(source1,text1,readable1, ...

Error in comparisons_private (line 9)
        out = textdiff(varargin{:});

Error in visdiff (line 52)
    htmlOut = comparisons_private('textdiff',filename1,filename2,showchars);
```